# Doctrine 2 ORM - Mapping a property with one of multiple target classes

Tags: doctrine-orm, orm, zend-framework3

In my ZF3 application I want to map an entity "User" having a property "plan" to another entity with could be one of the following classes "PlanA", "PlanB" or "PlanC" using Doctrine 2 ORM. A "User" can have one "Plan", a "Plan" can be associated with many "Users".

I looked into discriminator maps, but I am not sure that that's the right approach.

Any ideas/code sample for that?

Comment: Hi biyk! A whole article about inheritance within doctrine can be found here, including some good code snippets: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Comment: Is there any specific reason to create 3 Plan entities ? why not a single entity for Plans and define planType property inside entity

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid this is what i went for in the end, which is ok. would still be interesting how to solve it using different tables.